# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk Data Protection

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to know a few things about how amazon handles the data withing beanstalk:

Where is the data located - is it possible to find out? How long will the data be stored? And what happens the data gets deleted? Can you backup lost data or broken data? What kind of security is added to protect the data?

Thanks in advance!

best regards